# Check if data attribute is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I wish to map through all the `td`'s/cells in a table and check for their `data` attributes. If the attribute/his assigned value is not empty, I would like to `console.log` it.

I got this for now but it does not seem to work properly(It just says that all of the `td`'s are not empty). Also, I am not sure why the `this` inside the map function points to the `window` object but not to the exact `td`. Any ideas what am I missing?

```
function checkTds() {
    var $tab = $('table td');
    $.map($tab, function(){
        console.log($(this));
        if ($tab.attr("custom-data-attribute") !== "") {
            console.log($(this));
        }
    });
}

checkTds();
```

Comment: you should be using `$tab.map()`, not `$.map($tab)`

Comment: Both ways work. Since a nodelist can be iterated in jQuery you can also use `$tab.map()`.

Comment: you can, but they're not the same. `.map()` is specifically for working with jquery collections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `map` which assigns its own variable to the iterated list:

From the [*documentation*](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

> callback
>   Type: Function( Object elementOfArray, Integer indexInArray ) => Object 
>   The function to process each item against. The first argument to the function is the array item, the second argument is the index in array The function can return any value. A returned array will be flattened into the resulting array. Within the function, this refers to the global (window) object.

It is also standard to use the prefix `data` to make your custom attributes: `data-«yourname»`.

```js
function checkTds() {
  var $tab = $('table td');
  $.map($tab, function(element) {

    //look at the element var here
    //also check if the attribute exists!
    if ($(element).attr("custom-data-attribute") && $(element).attr("custom-data-attribute") !== "") {
      console.log($(element).attr("custom-data-attribute"));
    }
  });
}

checkTds();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td custom-data-attribute="1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td custom-data-attribute="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

On a side note: I personally would advise against using variables with the prefix `$` while using jQuery. It makes it more easy to confuse them with actual jQuery functions.

Comment: I see...Ok now when I use the element variable it does print all the td's, but I would like it to print only those which have some value assigned to it(and show that value). This is how my td looks like: <td class="cell" custom-data-attribute="lorem ipsum"></td>

Comment: Look at the stack snippet I've added.

Comment: Can also use `.length` instead of `!== ""`.